# Creating and Appending PHP Log Files Into a file under a folder inside S3 Bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am creating a PHP backend for a web application. Now I need to log all API calls into a log file. Now the logic is to create a log file inside the server itself and append the same file when new API calls are made. I am using AWS S3 file storage for image uploading, I wonder what if I can implement the log file creation and appending this log file in a specific folder called **logs** in my S3 bucket.

Is it possible to achieve creating a new log file inside S3 bucket (not uploading into s3 from local) and appending local API call logs into it?

My local code for log creation is given bellow:

```
$log  = "--------------------------------------".PHP_EOL.
"UserIP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' - '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL.
       "Request Data: ".$req_dump.PHP_EOL.
       "Request Method: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].PHP_EOL.
       "API URL: ".$actual_link.PHP_EOL.
       "File Name: ".$filename.PHP_EOL.
       "--------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;

       // $fp = fopen('../api_logs/request.txt', 'a');
       // $fw = fwrite($fp, $log);
       // fclose($fp);
       $fp = file_put_contents( '../api_logs/request.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Amazon stream wrapper allow you to store and retrieve data from Amazon S3 using built-in PHP functions like `file_get_contents`, `fopen`, `copy`, `rename`, `unlink`, `mkdir`, `rmdir`, etc

You can stream data to the file something like below:

```
$stream = fopen('s3://bucket/key', 'a');
fwrite($stream, 'Hello!');
fclose($stream);
```

Full documentation of Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html)